# How do I enable ciphers for NSS?

Tags: curl, nss

I am trying to use **curl** built with **NSS** (not built with OpenSSL) on Fedora 14 to connect to a webpage over https. The server to which I am connecting (example.com) uses the RC4-SHA cipher for its SSL. Whenever I try to connect to example.com, I get the NSS error `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP`. I can connect via curl on this computer to example-2.com which has the DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA cipher. I can connect to example.com from a different computer that has curl built with OpenSSL.

How do I find out which ciphers are enabled on NSS and how do I enable the RC4-SHA cipher on NSS?

Comment: Try `curl --url https://example.com/ --cipher rsa_rc4_128_sha`